# Using Namespace for multitenancy in google app Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to use multitenancy, in order to do that I'm using namespaces. The problem I am facing is that everytime I set the namespace, it goes back to null. 
I'm calling this filter for every URL on my application, so for example on the login page. When I validate the the login information I am supposed to get the user login and set the namespace. This is correctly done, but after that .. when I get back into that method on another URL "NamespaceManaget.get()" returns null.

Here is the code of my MultitenancyServlet

```
public class MultiTenancyServlet implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,  FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String client = req.getParameter("login");
    String nameSpace = NamespaceManager.get();

    if(nameSpace == null){
        NamespaceManager.set(client);
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on why am I having this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The namespace needs to be set on a per-request basis, because your application instance should have no state.

The example code in the [Multi tenancy documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy) does show a null check, but this is to check if another filter executed in the same request has already set the namespace to something else - not that a previous request set the namespace.

Comment: I get it now. 
Is using session a good practice to do make this work ?